# Mui date range picker always select first day of year

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, jalali-calendar, mui-x-date-picker

Im working on a react porject using mui components
I have this dateRangerPicker from mui components

```
<DateRangePicker
    localeText={{start: 'از تاریخ', end: 'تا تاریخ'}}
    id="create_date"
    value={filter.createDate}
    onChange={newValue => setFilter({...filter, createDate: newValue})}>
</DateRangePicker>
```

and this is state vlue

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
        createDate: [
            moment('2023-05-01'),
            moment('2023-11-01')],
        leaveDate: [null, null],
        name: '',
        type: 0,
        group: 0
    });
```

And this is localization provider and jalalli adapter

```
import {LocalizationProvider} from "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro";
import {AdapterMomentJalaali} from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/AdapterMomentJalaali';
```

and also i used localization provider with jalalli date adapter
so my problem is when i pick a date with calendar in ui, `start` part of the date will always first day of year. like '1402-01-01'. (Its jalalli calendar). but 2nd part of date is correct.
There is no problem if i use AdapterMoment instead of AdapterMomentJalalli for dateAdapter, but is there any way to solve this?

I just expect this work currecly with jallali calendar